JFXPanel don't show after dispose
I convert a pane component in a composable ui by swing pannel
package ui.pdfpreview

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberUpdatedState
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.awt.SwingPanel
import com.geolo.desktop.common.utils.LogUtils
import eu.patrickgeiger.fxpdf.util.PDF
import eu.patrickgeiger.fxpdf.viewer.MinimalViewer
import javafx.application.Platform
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane
import java.io.File

@Composable
fun PdfPreview(
    state: PdfPreviewState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onCreated: (MinimalViewer) -> Unit = {},
    onDispose: (MinimalViewer) -> Unit = {},
) {
    var minimalViewer by remember { mutableStateOf<MinimalViewer?>(null) }
    val currentOnDispose by rememberUpdatedState(onDispose)

    minimalViewer?.let {
        DisposableEffect(it) {
            onDispose {
                LogUtils.i("linlian pdfpreview onDispose minimalViewer=$minimalViewer ")
                it.pdf.closeDocument() //关闭文档
                currentOnDispose(it)
            }
        }
    }


    SwingPanel(factory = {
        JFXPanel().also { jfxP ->
            Platform.runLater {
                val rootVewView = MinimalViewer.MinimalViewerBuilder()
                    .setPDF(PDF(File(state.filePath)))
                    .build()
                minimalViewer = rootVewView
                val root = StackPane()
                root.children.add(minimalViewer)
                val scene = Scene(root)
                onCreated.invoke(rootVewView)
                jfxP.scene = scene
            }
        }

    }, modifier = modifier) {jfxpannel->
        LogUtils.i("linlian pdfpreview update minimalViewer=$minimalViewer ")
        LogUtils.i("linlian pdfpreview update jfxpannel=$jfxpannel ")
    }


}

class PdfPreviewState(
    val filePath: String
)






and use it in compose
 PdfPreview(pdfPreviewState, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    onCreated = {
                        LogUtils.i("linlian PdfPreview onCreated")
                    }, onDispose = {
                        LogUtils.i("linlian PdfPreview onDispose")
                    })


it works well in first time,but after I quit page and open it again,
the code in Platform.runLater won't run, so the page is blank.

Does calling Platform.setImplicitExit(false) solve the problem? Based on your description of the problem, that would be the more appropriate solution. Though I'm not completely sure how JFXPanel interacts with the "implicit exit" rules. Note you only have to call setImplicitExit once, at the start of the application. Also note you are now responsible for ensuring JavaFX exits when appropriate (by calling Platform.exit()).

Where should I insert 'setImplicitExit'

As far as I know, anywhere you want before the "implicit exit" takes effect. If this were a plain JavaFX application, I would put it in the override of Application#start(Stage). But you're embedding JavaFX in Swing. So assuming setImplicitExit works the same in this case, you could try putting it in your main method.

add Platform.enterNestedEventLoop("main") in the last line of Platform.runLater{}
